# How to make data from one table which is having large data in millions to another table in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-insert, sqlbulkcopy

I have a table with millions of rows. I need to insert data from this table into another table in the same database.

How do I insert the data from one table to another table in bulk using sql query in SQL Server 2012.

Comment: `INSERT INTO SELECT`. Good luck.

Comment: This is *extremely* easy to Google. Even googling `How do I insert the data from one table to another table in bulk using sql query in SQL Server 2012.` leads to a result.

Comment: Do you want all rows, or just a few of them? If millions of rows, I'd consider copying it in parts, to keep transaction size reasonably small.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * INTO NewTableName FROM OldTableName
```

Try this.

Comment: If the table he wants to insert into already exists, then this will fail. This will work only when the destination table does not exist.

Comment: yeah I understand. but I have provided the solution for new table. he should be able to understand this thing.

Answer (score 0):

you can create and populate a table in sql server very easy like this :

```
select *
into   NewTable
from   yourtable
```

and when you want to copy into an existing table you can use this

```
insert into existingtable (field1, field2,...)
select field1, field2,... from yourtable
```

Comment: not anymore, i uncluded copying into an existing table also